# What is this connector on my UPS called?

Tags: connector, ups

I need to get a hold of a connector to mate with the socket in the following image, but I don't know what this type of connector is called.

The socket is an external battery connector on a PowerWalker UPS.

Can anyone help me identify it?

[image: Unidentified connector]

Comment: Let me warn you not to connect anything not recommended by the manufacturer of the UPS. Batteries may have fuses in their assembly (or within their cable), and if you do things wrong you risk to fire your compartment, or whole building. You ***must*** use approved battery device with the UPS. And those approved batteries of course will have needed mating connector.

Comment: That said, if your UPS has an thermostat controlled fan, you should be fine. Which it will almost certainly have if it comes with an external battery connector. Just confirm the battery chemistry - if it's AGM batteries, then it will gas if you connect normal or sealed lead acid batteries as AGM has a slightly higher float voltage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like Anderson SB50. 
[image]
[Link to manufacturer](http://www.andersonpower.com/us/en/products/sb-sb-boots/sb-50.aspx)

Comment: aka AMP POWER Series 50 - [drawings](http://www.te.com/commerce/DocumentDelivery/DDEController?Action=srchrtrv&DocNm=647845&DocType=Customer+Drawing&DocLang=English&DocFormat=pdf)

Comment: @Finbarr A beloved child has many names - Swedish proverb.

Comment: A problem child probably has lots of names too :)

Comment: PowerWalker uses battery connectors made by ANEN according to https://powerwalker.com/datasheets/Accessories/PowerWalker%20Battery%20Pack%2010120575.pdf. A Yellow Anderson  SB50A (APC 24V UPS) won't fit in my PowerWalker UPS because there are at least 4 **mechanical different keys** versions of the SB50 / Power Serie 50 connectors. https://powerwalker.com/manuals/_BP/SOP%20-%20How%20to%20assemble%20BP%20A36T-6x9Ah.pdf shows red battery pack connectors.

Answer (score 0):

## ANEN SA50B8-H

According to [battery pack datasheets](https://powerwalker.com/datasheets/Accessories/PowerWalker%20Battery%20Pack%2010120575.pdf) PowerWalker uses battery connectors from ANEN.

According to http://uk.anen-power.com/UploadFiles/Spec/SA50%E8%A7%84%E6%A0%BC%E4%B9%A6.pdf page 3, the part number for the gray housing is SA50B8-H.

[image: ANEN Power SA50 connector image]